# What does $\mathbf{1}$ mean in $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \mathbf{1}${$X_m=i$} here?

Tags: notation, markov-chains

In the below passage, I was wondering what $\mathbf{1}$ signifies:

> How much time does a Markov chain spend in state $i$, in the long term? That is, what is the long term fraction of time that $X_n=i$ ? We can write this long term fraction of time as
> $
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \mathbf{1}${$X_m=i$}

The text goes on to say that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \mathbf{1}${$X_m=i$} counts the number of steps among {$0,1,\ldots,n-1$} where $X_m= i$ - however, being unsure of what $\mathbf{1}$ means, notationally, I have been unable to see this.

I would greatly appreciate an explanation as to the meaning of $\mathbf{1}$ and how such means that expressions counts the number of steps among that set where $X_m = i$.

Comment: Indicator / characteristic function. Alternatively written by $\chi_{\{X_m=i\}}$

Comment: It means $1$ if $X_m=i$, and $0$ if $X_m\ne i$. (In case you don't know what an indicator / characteristic function is!)

Comment: Note:  the sum counts the number of such occurrences, but your expression has a factor of $\frac 1n$ so it counts the portion of $\{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}$ that passes the test.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf 1\{X_m = i\}$ is the *indicator function* or *characteristic function* of the event $\{X_m = i\}$, defined by
$$\mathbf 1\{X_m = i\}  = \begin{cases} 1 & X_m = i, \\ 0 & X_m \ne i.\end{cases}$$
So $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n-1} \mathbf 1\{X_m = i\}$ counts the number of visits by the chain to state $i$ up to time $n-1$. Thus $\frac 1n \sum_\limits{m=0}^{n-1} \mathbf 1\{X_m = i\}$ is the proportion of time before $n$ spent in state $i$.

In the context of Markov chains, given some irreducible chain with invariant distribution $\pi$, the *ergodic theorem* states that
$$\frac 1n \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \mathbf 1\{X_m = i\}\to \pi(i) \quad \text{as } n \to \infty $$
with probability $1$. That is, the long-term proportion of time spent in each state is described precisely by the invariant distribution.